# Determine whether pandas dataframe with missing values is subset of another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes. They both share the same columns. The first is larger, and contains no missing values, e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_full = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["apple", "apple", "banana"],
    "b": [1, 2, 1]
})
```

```
        a  b
0   apple  1
1   apple  2
2  banana  1
```

The second has fewer rows, and can contain missing values

```
df_partial = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["apple", "apple"],
    "b": [np.nan, np.nan]
})
```

```
       a   b
0  apple NaN
1  apple NaN
```

I want to determine whether `df_partial` can be obtained by deleting rows and elements from `df_full`, and reordering rows. Or to put it another way, can we match every row in `df_partial` to a unique row in `df_full`, where a row matches if its non-missing elements are equal.

So in the example above, `df_partial` can be obtained as described above because we can match the first two rows of `df_partial` with the first two rows of `df_full` (in either order).

Alternatively, the dataframe

```
df_partial2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["banana"],
    "b": [2]
})
```

```
        a  b
0  banana  2
```

cannot be obtained as described as there is no row in `df_full` that matches.

Finally, a slightly trickier case, the dataframe

```
df_partial3 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["apple", "apple", np.nan],
    "b": [1, 2, 2]
})
```

```
       a  b
0  apple  1
1  apple  2
2    NaN  2
```

cannot be obtained as described because even though you can match every row in `df_partial3` to a row in `df_full`, you can't choose *unique* rows from `df_full` to match everything in `df_partial3`.

Some additional considerations:

- This should be general to any number of rows/columns
- You can solve this by just looping through all possible injective mappings from rows of `df_partial` to rows of `df_full`, but I would like something much more efficient if possible

**EDIT**: One thing I didn't make clear above. The order of the rows does not matter. So for example, the dataframe

```
df_partial4 = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["apple", "apple"],
    "b": [np.nan, 1]
})
```

```
       a  b
0  apple  NaN
1  apple  1
```

can be obtained as described, even though we have to match the second row in `df_partial4` with the first row in `df_full`, and the first row of `df_partial4` with the second row in `df_full`.

Comment: Lookup the maximum matching problem. There is no easier solution.

Comment: Thanks @user202729, I have updated the question to indicate that rows may be rearranged.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for the pointer to the maximum matching problem - looks like my problem is a bipartite matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user202729 for the suggestion to look up the maximum matching problem.
Here is the solution I ended up using.

**TL;DR:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import maximum_bipartite_matching
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

def is_match(df_partial, df_full):
    full = df_full.to_numpy()
    partial = df_partial.to_numpy()
    nans = df_partial.isna().to_numpy()
    matches = (full[:, np.newaxis, :] == partial) | nans
    adjacency_matrix = matches.all(axis=2)
    matching = maximum_bipartite_matching(csr_matrix(adjacency_matrix))
    return (matching >= 0).all()
```

---

Below I go through the steps in a little more detail, using the first example given in the question.

First we create a matrix where element i, j is `True` if row i of `full_df` matches row j of `partial_df` and false otherwise.

```
full = df_full.to_numpy()
partial = df_partial.to_numpy()
nans = df_partial.isna().to_numpy()

# Use numpy broadcasting to get a pairwise row comparison
matches = (full[:, np.newaxis, :] == partial) | nans
adjacency_matrix = matches.all(axis=2)
```

```
[[ True  True]
 [ True  True]
 [False False]]
```

We can think of this as the adjacency matrix of a bipartite graph, where vertices are the rows in our dataframes, and edges go between rows that are matched. We want to know if we can match every row in `df_partial` to a row in `df_full`. A more general question is, what is the maximum number of rows in `df_partial` that we can match in `df_full`.

This question is known as the bipartite maximum matching problem, and can be solved using the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm. As far as I can tell, this is the most efficient known solution to the problem. There is an implementation of this in scipy.

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import maximum_bipartite_matching
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


matching = maximum_bipartite_matching(csr_matrix(adjacency_matrix))
```

```
[0 1]
```

The scipy function, `maximum_bipartite_matching`, uses a -1 to indicate vertices that cannot be matched so if there are no -1 values, then `df_partial` is a "subset" of `df_full`.

```
is_subset = (matching >= 0).all()
```

```
True
```